# ios-Update multiple UIViews on UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a ViewController that contain a UIScrollView, that contains a few views which are custom UIViews (very simple uiimage + uibutton) that the user can scroll between (one custom view at the a time).
I want the user to be able to "mark" a photo, and then to display a certain text, when the user select a different photo (by using the button), I want to update the text on the previous selected photo and the current selected.

What should I do?
Inside the view itself I don't have access to the previous view, I figured I should send a notification to the view controller but than I have no access to the button I want to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use tags to identify the scrollViews subviews.
Add a tag to the subview and the same tag to the button that belongs to the subview while adding them to the scrollView.

```
view.tag = 1;
button.tag = 1;
```

Then in the method called by the buttons, you can use the buttons tag to get the according custom view.

```
-(void)buttonClick:(id)sender{
   UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
   NSInteger tag = btn.tag;
   UIView* customView = [self.scrollView viewWithTag:tag];
}
```

To access the prevoius selected view, store the tag of that view when editing for the next call of the function.

Comment: thanks! totally forgot about this option of using tags.